# Preventing corrosion of copper PCB tracks

Tags: pcb, pcb-fabrication

I do DIY PCB with the following steps:

```
1) Apply the circuit diagram on a presensitized PCB via an UV lamp
2) place it into positive developer (NaOH)
3) clean it via water
4) place it into an etching solution (sodium persulfate)
5) clean it via water
6) dry it then clean it via Acetone (to solder easier)
7) drill & solder
```

I produced several PCBs and noticed that the copper parts are getting corroded in a month or so.

What chemical/material do I need to apply in order to prevent them to get corroded? I guess that procedure should be done after step 6, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Tin plating](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plating#Tin_plating) will prevent the copper from oxidizing or tarnishing. Comes in [liquid form](http://www.mgchemicals.com/products/prototyping-and-circuit-repair/prototyping/liquid-tin-421/) too, so you just need to paint it on or dip the board in.

Answer (score 5):

Spray paint laquer on it. After you have soldered everything on and tested the board. Or a good coat of varnish. Not kidding: [Can acrylic latex spray paint be used as a DIY solder mask?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/35202/can-acrylic-latex-spray-paint-be-used-as-a-diy-solder-mask)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use conformal coating that will protect from oxidation as well as provide isolation

As with all chemicals, be careful not to inhale or misuse. Use in open air.