# PCBA corrosion voltage dependence

Tags: pcb, high-voltage, failure, humidity, corrosion

Let’s say a PCBA is located in a humid environment where condensation can occur in a worst-case scenario. Parts of the PCBA are low voltage circuitry and parts are high voltage, let’s say we have 3.3V DC and AC, 230 DC and AC and 2kV DC and AC all present on the board.

Given proper clearances and creepages:

Will the parts of the PCB (copper traces and pads) with high voltage faster succumb to corrosion and other moisture-related failures?

Will the parts of PCB exposed to AC or high frequency voltages experience problems faster that those which are exposed to DC?

Comment: It's probably yes to both questions. Use varnish or lacquer on exposed soldered connections is my advice.

Comment: Although I don't agree with general praise of conformal coating, there is some information on this topic (specifically voltage gradients) in another thread: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/5095/whats-the-best-way-to-protect-a-board-from-corrosion-in-a-hot-moist-environment?rq=1

Comment: In my experience most coatings with few exceptions (parylene, molded epoxy) give only marginal protection.